# Equivalent sets proof

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a set. Show that $\cal P(A)$ - the power set of $A$ - is equivalent (same cardinal) to ${\{0, 1\}}^A$ - the set of all functions from $A$ to $\{0, 1\}$. Suppose $A$ was $\mathbb{N}$; would this hold? How about if $A$ was $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ (the set of sequences with values in $\mathbb{N}$)?

My friend gave me the following proof:

It suffices to construct a bijective function.

Suppose that $f: A \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$, and let $A_f$ be the set of elements such that $a\in  A_f \iff f(a)=1$. Define the map $h(f) =A_f$ then we proceed to show injectivity and surjectivity:

Injectivity:

Suppose that for functions $f, g$, we have $f\ne g$. Then there is an $x\in A$ so $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=0$ or vice versa. Then $A_f\ne A_g$. By the contrapositive argument, $h$ is injective.

Surjectivity:

Let $X\in{\cal P}(A)$ and then define a function $f$ as follows:

$$f(x)=\cases{1, if x\in B\cr 0, if x \notin B }$$

Then $X = h(f)$ and $h$ is surjective.

We have a bijection $h:{\{0, 1\}}^A \rightarrow {\cal P}(A)$ so, we may conclude that the two sets are equivalent.

Is this proof correct? Is there a more formal or more detailed way to express it? In addition, does this proof carry forward to $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ defined in the problem above? Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't quite how I would write it (for example I would be clearer about what $h$ was a function from and to, which your context makes clear but might not be clear to a random reader of the argument), and I might include more narrative just being explicit about what it means for things to be one-to-one and onto. But the core ideas are clear and correct and that is definitely exactly how I would approach the problem. It isn't immediately clear to me why the specific identity of $A$ would matter.

Comment: The proof holds for $any$ set $A$.

Comment: @leslietownes Would the proof above require any further steps to be recognized as formal or is what is above sufficient?

Comment: Why don't you think it is formal?  Seems formal to me.

Comment: @fleablood The injectivity and surjectivity don't seem to be "enough"...

Comment: Why in blood's name not?  That's the *very* definition of to sets having the same cardinality.  That means that is an injective/surjective function between them.  What "more" could it possibly mean.  And that *very* formall finds the bijection.

Comment: @fleablood No I understand that part. Perhaps I haven't had enough experience with such but his proof of the injectivity and surjectivity seems lacking in explanation. In particular, how can one conclude surjectivity by just defining a function?

Comment: If you want to prove $f:M \to N$ is surjective, all you have to do is show that for *any* $n \in N$ you can find/define/create an element $m\in M$ so that $f(m) = N$.  As the elements if $\{0,1\}^A$ are functions $A\to \{0,1\}$ then *defining* a function is *EXACTLY* the way to find an element....  The element you found *is* that function you just invented.

Comment: This sort of gets at my earlier comment. $h$ as defined is a function from $\{0,1\}^A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$. It might not hurt simply to mention that (it's clear from context but often people reading these things like to see the domain and codomain expressly identified when a function is defined). To prove $h$ is surjective one must, as you do, fix $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and produce $f \in \{0,1\}^A$ with $h(f) = X$. So you *do* show that $h$ is surjective by "defining a function" (in a way that works for any $X$ in the codomain of $h$).

Comment: There is considerable variation in how much proofs like this walk you back through the definitions of the things you are proving (e.g. what it means for a function to be injective or surjective, with the ingredients of the proof simply "plugged in" to them before any subsequent analysis or comment is made, e.g. "to show that $h$ is injective, we must show that $h(f) = h(g)$ implies $f=g$."). This is not really being more "formal"; I see it more as a stylistic choice than anything else. But it can help convey to the reader, or yourself, that your argument is in fact doing what it sets out to do

Comment: @leslietownes This makes a lot of sense! In my experience, proofs are often a little complicated to follow when not enough has been explained. Thank you for your response(s)!

Comment: I think the hardest thing for this and proofs like it, is to really *grock* what the terms $\{0,1\}^A$ and $\mathscr P(A)$ *mean* and to picture what a function $\phi:\mathscr P(A) \to \{0,1\}^A$ or $\psi: \{0,1\}^A \to \mathscr P(A)$ would *look* like.  But  once you get if $f:A \to \{0, 1\}$ is a function so that $f(x)=$ either $0$ or $1$ and $E_f \subset A$ based somehow on what the function $f$ does, then $f\in \{0,1\}^A$ and $E_f \in \mathscr P(A)$ and we HAVE "mapped" $f \mapsto E_f$.  So that *is* what is going on. Do that for every element and we have $\psi:\{0,1\}^A\to\mathscr P(A)$.

Comment: @fleablood I think I will use your approach from now on.

Comment: I look at my comment .... and I see Symbol Soup.  But if you *get* the concepts they really *are* simple. And the alternative to Symbol Soup is literary "the man who shot the man who got shot by the man who shot him used a gun that shot the man who got shot by the man who shot the man who got shot" block that referrer linguistic quagmire.  And that can be worse.

Comment: @fleablood Any chance I could get your help with the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036232/limit-with-a-set-proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be more direct.

Let $f\in \{0,1\}^A$.  Then $f$ is a function $f: A \to \{0,1\}$

Consider $\{a\in A| f(a) = 1\}$.  That's well defined subset of $A$.

And so $\phi:\{0,1\}^A\to \mathscr P(A)$ via $\phi(f) = \{a\in A| f(a) = 1\}$ is a well-defined function.

Now its just a matter of proving it is surjective and injective.

1. It is surjective.

Let $E\subset A$.  Define $g:A\to \{0,1\}$ via $g(a) =\begin{cases}1&a\in E\\0&a\not \in E\end{cases}$.  $g$ is a well defined function from $A\to \{0,1\}$. so $g \in \{0,1\}^A$.

Because that's what $\{0,1\}^A$ ***is***:  Its the collection of all possible functions for $A\to \{0,1\}$ and $g$ *certainly* is a function that for every element of $A$ maps distinctly to either $0$ or $1$.

And $\phi(g)=\{a\in A|g(a)=1\} = \{a\in A|a \in E\} =E$.

SO for all $E\in \mathscr P(A)$ there a $g\in \{0,1\}^A$ so that $\phi(g) = E$. So $\phi$ is surjective.

2. It is injective.

$f, g\in \{0, 1\}^A$ and $\phi(f)=\phi(g)=E$.  Then for every $a \in A$ we have either $a\in E$ in which case $f(a)=g(a) = 1$; or $a \not \in E$ in which case $f(a)=g(a)=0$. In either case $f(a) =g(a)$ for all $a \in A$.

So $f = g$.  For any $f,g \in \{0,1\}$ we have $\phi(f)=\phi(g) \iff f=g$ so $\phi$ is injective.

....

ANd that's that.

....

This will hold of $A = \mathbb N$ or $A =\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ or for *any* set.

$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$.  We can find a one-to-correspondence between any subset of the natural numbers to a function (and vice versa) by for each subset considering the function where $f(n)=1$ if $n \in A\subset \mathbb N$ and $f(m) = 0$ if $m\not \in A$.

......

COuld you try harder to put your finger on what in your gut doesn't feel right because this is utterly complete and formal and foolproof so far as I can tell.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I note that it avoids a mild infelicity of notation in the original, where the notations $h(f)$ and $A_f$ are redundant, and perhaps the use of $A$ in $A_f$ arguably invites confusion (in some, but not in me) with the set $A$ that begins the problem.  (If you called it $B_f$ there would be no trouble with just calling the function $B$, skipping $h$ entirely, and describing its action by $f \mapsto B_f$ or $B(f)$. Whereas $A$ cannot double as a function and the name of the original set). It is certainly cleaner with less notation.

Comment: @fleablood Oh my God! Check that, Oh my Blood! This is far more detailed! Thank you for that!

Comment: Also, wouldn't the case that $A = \mathbb{N}$ imply that the cardinality of $\cal P(\mathbb{N})$ is equal to that of $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$? So the power set of naturals has the cardinality $2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$?

Comment: Yes Indeed!  $|\mathscr P(\mathbb N)| = |\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}| =2^{\mathbb N}=  |\mathbb R| = |$ all countably infinite sequences of $0$ and $1| =|$ all sequences of natural numbers$| = |$ all function of natural numbers to any countable set|--- is one of the *fundamental* and well known results of cardinality.

Comment: Consider this (You might as well see it now... you *will* see it later).  Let $x\in \mathbb R$.  Express $x$ is as a binary decimal.  Let $\mathbb N\supset A = \{n\in \mathbb N|$ the $n$th digit of $x$ as a binary is equal to $1\}$.  That's a 1-1 mapping from  $\mathbb R$ to$\mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ .  ... well actually it's only a mapping from the  real interval $[0, 1]\subset\mathbb R$ to $\mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ but we can make modifications to get it to work from all $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @fleablood Have any recommendations where I can read more about $\cal P(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{R}$? By the way, with proofs like yours, you should contribute to proof wiki (the proofs there are much too complex) or start a Youtube channel!

Comment: @fleablood Cleaner way to say it: Let $A: [0, 1] \to P(N)$ such that $A(x) = \{n \in N \mid \text{the $n$th binary digit of $x$ is $1$}\}$. Then $A$ is bijective so $[0, 1] \equiv \mathcal{P}(N)$ as sets and hence $\bf{R} \equiv \mathcal{P}(N)$ as sets.

Comment: @Kraftsman Re: book recommendation: Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* is an analysis book that covers all the elementary set theory discussed in this answer and its comments. It's aimed at undergrads taking a first analysis course and has lots of exercises with solutions, which you might find useful for self-study

Comment: @Asker cleaner maybe.  It's  a trade of.  Sometimes thinking *functions* that take *sets* as single elements output (or input), or other functions as input or elements, is an abstract concepts many students have a mental block over.  But sometimes a casual "we have a set of subset here, and real number here, and we can assign a set to be number by so and so" avoids the mental block (even though it the exact same thing!)