# Limit with a set proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $x_n = n^{-1}$ and let $X \subset \mathbb{N}$ so that $\sum_{n \in X} x_n$ is convergent. Define $p(m) = 2^m$ and let $Y = \{x \in X | p(m) \leq x < p(m+1)\}$. Prove that $\liminf_{m\to\infty} \frac{cardinal(Y)}{p(m)}$ converges to $0$.

This is what I have so far:

Assume $\sum_{n \in X} x_n$ converges. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$.By definition of the limit, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n| = |n^{-1}| = |\frac{1}{n}| < \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$

We need that $\liminf_{m\to\infty} \frac{cardinal(Y)}{p(m)} = 0$. We require an $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|\frac{cardinal(Y)}{p(m)}| = \frac{cardinal(Y)}{p(m)} < \epsilon_2$ for $n \geq N_2$.

I have no idea how to solve this problem particularly because it spans and requires arguments from two topics: sets and limits. Any assistance is appreciated.

Edit: I tried using the comparison test as an argument but to no avail.

Comment: Just double checked and the definitions are fine. If it helps, it can also be written as $Y = \{x \in X| 2^m \leq x < 2^{m+1}\}$ and $\liminf_{m\to\infty} \frac{card(Y)}{2^m}$ to avoid the $p(m)$ definition altogether. Even more simply: $\liminf_{m\to\infty} \frac{card(\{x \in X| 2^m \leq x < 2^{m+1}\})}{2^m}$

Comment: I agree that the question is much clearer if one simply writes $2^m$ in place of $p(m)$ and $1/n$ in place of $x_n$. The contrapositive of the statement is "if $\liminf \#Y/2^m>0$ then $\sum_{n\in X} 1/n$ diverges"; can you prove that statement?

Comment: @GregMartin I'm not sure how to manipulate $\liminf$ sheerly due to lack of experience with infimums. Could you explain?

Comment: Also easier if you use a variable *other* than $x$ in the definition $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reach into your bag of tricks of what looks familiar.

We know $\frac 11 + \frac 12 +\frac 13 +.... = \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} x_n$ diverges.

And we prove $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}x_n$ diverges because $\frac 1{2^m} + \frac 1{2^m+1} + ..... + \frac 1{2^{m+1} - 1} > \frac 1{2^{m+1}} + \frac 1{2^{m+1}} + ..... + \frac 1{2^{m+1}} = 2^m\times \frac 1{2^{m+1}} = \frac 12$ so

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1k = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=2^{m}}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac 1k )> \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac 12 = \infty$.

Now to use the notation of the problem If we let $W(m) = \{2^m,2^m + 1,..... 2^{m+1}-1\}=\{n\in \mathbb N|2^n\le n< 2^{m+1}\}= \{w\in \mathbb N: p(m) \le w < p(m)\}\supseteq \{x\in X|p(m) \le x < p(m)\} = Y_m$

So we have for each $n\in Y(m)$ then $2^m = p(m)\le n < p(m+1)=2^{m+1}$ then $x_n = \frac 1n \ge \frac 1{p(m+1)}$ and $\sum_{n\in Y(m)} x_n > \frac 1{p(m+1)}\times |Y_m|$

And $\sum_{w\in X}x_w=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{w\in Y(m)} x_w > \sum_{m=0} \frac {|Y_m|}{p(m+1)}$

But this converges so $\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac {|Y_m|}{p(m+1)}= \lim_{m\to \infty} \frac {|Y_m|}{2p(m)}= 0$.  So $\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac {|Y_m|}{p(m)} = 0$. and $0\le \lim \inf_{m\to\infty}\frac {|Y_m|}{p(m)} \le \lim_{m\to \infty} \frac {|Y_m|}{p(m)} = 0$

Comment: Although the notation is a little iffy (example: switch of $Y_m$ with $Y(m)$), I think I get most of it. How did you find that $\sum_{m=0} \frac{|Y_m|}{p(m+1)}$ converges?

Comment: A continuation from my first comment: Is it by the direct comparison test? Also, was the inequality you proved a result of the subset shown just prior?

Comment: "this" refers to $\sum_{w\in X} x_w$.  It converges because were told it does.

Comment: So it was by direct comparison. I like this proof. Thank you once again Mr. Blood.

Comment: Hi @fleablood. You were really helpful before so I was wondering if I could I get your help here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4066118/812835

Answer (score 1):

Since the set $X$ is a subset of the naturals, and the sum converges absolutely, you can assume that the sequence $x_n$ can be rearranged to be monotonically decreasing.

The sequence $p(m)$ partitions $X$, so you can bound the sum in terms of contributions from each block:

$$\sum_{n}x_n\geq \sum_m \frac{|Y(m)|}{p(m+1)}.$$

Suppose otherwise that the liminf is a positive number. Then there's a positive number $c>0$ and a sequence $m_k$ such that $|Y(m_k)|/p(m_k)\geq c$ for all $k>0$. So the above sum can be bounded:

$$\sum_{n}x_n\geq \sum_{k} \frac{cp(m_k)}{p(m_k+1)}= \sum_{k} c/2=\infty $$